# Groovy - Modify xml file value

Tags: java, android, gradle, groovy, scripting

I have an XML file and I am pasting my xml file below. I want to change the value of splash_color using a groovy script. I have tried to parse it but not able to succeed.
XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="splash_color">#D3B61A</color>
</resources>
```

Groovy Code:

```
def xmlFile = "$androidWorkingDirPath/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml"
    def xml = new XmlParser().parse(xmlFile)
    xml.color[0].each {
        //it.@name = "test2"
        //it.value = "test2"
        println("it.value=$it.value")
        println("it.value=$it.value.name")
    }
    new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(xmlFile))).println("Xmlvalue=$xml")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below works.

```
def xmlFile = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="splash_color">#D3B61A</color>
</resources>
'''
```

You can use `XmlUtil.serialize` instead of `new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter`...

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
```

I'm using `parseText()` because in this example I'm not reading from a file

```
def resources = new XmlParser().parseText(xmlFile)
```

You don't have to use `[0]` here, but if there are more nodes with the same name, use [findAll()](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_flexible_navigation_with_children_depthfirst_and_breadthfirst)

```
resources.color.each {
```

Use `${}` to interpolate variables in strings

```
    println "it.value=${it.value}" 
    println "it.name=${it.@name}"
}

println XmlUtil.serialize(resources)
```

You can pipe that to a file.

For the replacement of a node, see [this](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_modifying_removing_nodes)